# How to export variable data to a JSON file on the server using JavaScript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, variables

So let's say I have a HTML page and an input box on it. The user will type something in it, then I'll store it as a variable in JS, and then, can I somehow write the data of that variable to an already existing JSON file on the server?

How can I achieve this using JavaScript and/or PHP?

EDIT: I actually want to know how to write the data of a PHP variable to a JSON file that is in the same directory as the PHP file.

Comment: JS (clientside) can get that variable and handle it, but only a serverside language (PHP) can write to a file. There are many ways to do this, but all of them consist in sending that value to the server (via a form submit, or Ajax) and handling the file modification serverside(get that `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable and handle it).

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I want to know how to write the data of a php variable to a json file that is in the same directory as the .php file itself.

Comment: Ok, then, post what you have so far. Were you able to send the variable back to your PHP already, or not yet?

Comment: `$foo = json_decode(file_get_Contents('stuff.json')); $foo['newkey'] = 'newdata'; file_put_contents('stuff.json', json_encode($foo));`, basically

Comment: @MarcB `json_decode(..., TRUE)` to get an associative array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I'll try your solution now. @blex Yes, I did send my JS variables and saved them as php variables, using a html forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_put_contents("json_file.json",json_encode($array));
```

Result:

```
{"key":"value","anotherkey":"anothervalue"}
```

**Note:** file_put_contents function will overwrite your file!
**Edit:** appendable:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("json_file.json"),true);
$array['your_new_key'] = "your_new_value";
file_put_contents("json_file.json",json_encode($array));
```

Comment: One question though, is there a php function that doesn't overwrite the current content of the file? Thanks.

Comment: file_put_contents("json_file.json",json_encode($array), **FILE_APPEND**);

Comment: But simply appending it will produce invalid JSON -> `{"foo":"bar"}{"x":"z"}`

Comment: @blex yes, you are right :) i writing another code for you

Comment: You can "json_decode()" and append to array, again "json_encode()" then overwrite file

Comment: $array = json_decode(file_get_contents("json_file.json"),true); $array['your_new_key'] = "your_new_value"; file_put_contents("json_file.json",json_encode($array));